# displaying a message as pop up when my site is open

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a web php web site. I want to show a message on the pop up div when a user browse my site (home page). I need to show the message only the first time with in a browser.
Does anyone know?

Comment: you can use cookies to maintain this popup functionality....

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code of your approach so we can better help.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but as well meant advice: Don't do that. Such pop ups will only discourage people from using your site. Usually only aggressive advertisement does such pop ups. And it's not reliably possible to limit it to the first visit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no php in your question, it is only js and cookies.

The logic you want is:

- Does cookie <name> exist?
- yes

  - The user has been to your page/site before
  - do nothing
- no

  - The user is new
  - write cookie <name> with any value
  - run your "display message" function

Comment: call this function using method `onLoad` like `<body onLoad="myFunc()">`

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can do this using two step action, using either `sessions` or `cookies`

1. Show the div

   - Check if a parameter is previously set
   - If not show the div
2. Then set a parameter to confirm it is never again, till the browser is closed

Since other answers are focused on cookies, I will give you an example of session.

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['boxshowed']) || !$_SESSION['boxshowed'])) {
   echo "<div>to show</div>";
   $_SESSION['boxshowed'] = true;
}
```

Using sessions for this, will show the box again, when the user reopens the site, after completely closing it.

Answer (score 0):

[this is](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=67215) you may have to do (use the cookie to store that data)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set cookie for that in php and check if cookie value is set then don't show pop up message

Answer (score 0):

I think you can open browser easily, but your question is it should be open only first time even user refresh or reload page it should not display again.

1. Every time page will load it will check if they have cookie?
2. If they have then they do nothing.
3. If they do not have, then display poup and set cookie.